# GKMatchmaker custom matchmaker viewcontroller cancelled

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am implementing a custom matchmaker view controller and using GKMatchmaker to find a match for two players programmatically using:

```
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKMatch *thisMatch, NSError *error)
```

My custom matchmaker view controller has a button that allows a player to cancel a match via [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] cancel].

When Player 1 cancels a match, sometimes a GKMatch has already been created with Player 2. How do I notify Player 2 that Player 1 has cancelled the match and to start searching for another match?

I suppose the answer could lie in the GKMatchmakerViewController class and the code just before delegate method matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled is called. Does anyone know how I can get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with this, I realized that GKPlayerStateDisconnected in the following function takes a long while to get called when a player cancels a match after GKMatch is created but before players are connected:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)theMatch player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state
```

I got around this by calling the findMatchForRequest function again after ~15 seconds if GKMatch was created but players were not connected.

Would be interested to know if people have a more elegant solution.

Comment: did you ever find out more info on this?